# key press event change the value of list view in android

Tags: android

I have editbox and list view. I am adding the company name in list view. I have the requirement: suppose the user types 'A' in editview. I have to display only A value in list view and if the user types ab in editview, I have to display ab value in list view at the time of key press event. I have to change the value in list view in android.

Can anybody give an example?

Thanks

Comment: describe your problem little bit more.

Answer (score 0):

Take look at [AutoComplete](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html) and there is an [example](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-autocomplete.html) for it.

What you need to do here is basically fill the `COUNTRIES` array in the example with the values from your ListView